# Dependency not installed when installing Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse plugin. That is using UI and file resources. Which required `org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.8.101"` and filed if this dependency is not available on target eclipse.

Eclipse version: Juno (for Android development).

I want to install this jar if not available on target Eclipse. So my plugin run without any issue for target Eclipse.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ABC
Bundle-SymbolicName: ABC;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Activator: magic.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.8.101"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 libs/java-json.jar,
 libs/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
```

Here is the error I got while installation

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Feature 1.0.0 (com.confiz.android.codegen.feature.feature.group 1.0.0)
Missing requirement: Feature 1.0.0 (com.confiz.android.codegen.feature.feature.group 1.0.0) requires 'org.eclipse.core.resources 3.8.101' but it could not be found
```

Comment: `org.eclipse.core.resources` is included in all Eclipse installations.

Comment: Add error details as well.

Comment: You are probably trying to install on a version of Eclipse with an older version of org.eclipse.core.resources. You should not try to install a newer version as it may not be compatible. Do you actually need the 3.8.1 version of the plugin?

Comment: 3.8.101 is probably in Kepler SR1.